# How to merge two array of objects based on the fields OrderNo and Location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two API responses

1st API response (response of ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API1', null, null, requestBody)) - see later part of the question

```
[
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "46.1650",
"OrderDate": null,
"Status": null
}
```

]

2nd API response (response of ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API2', null, null, requestBody)) - see later part of the question

```
[
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "22.27",
"OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
"Status": null
},
{
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty": "21.94",
"OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty": "65.36",
"OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
"Status": null
 }
]
```

Now both APIs have a Qty field, I have to create a new variable where I need to have two quantities together. If for a particular OrderNo and Location combination say Qty1 - the first APIs response field Qty is present but 2nd APIs Qty field is not present then we should insert Qty2 as 0, similarly if Qty2 - the 2nd APIs response field Qty is present but 1st APIs Qty field not present then we should insert Qty1 as 0.

Also we have to consider that any one of the two API can completely return blank array

Please notice the comparing parameters are OrderNo and Location.

I want to basically merge the two API response and create a combinedResponse

My combined response must have three objects in the array of object

```
[
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty1": "46.1650",
"Qty2": "22.27",
"OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty1": "0",
"Qty2": "21.94",
"OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
"Status": null
  },
  {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty1": "0",
"Qty2": "65.36",
"OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
"Status": null
 }
]
```

I have used Lodash for these but I have getting some anomalous results

My Code

```
 ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API1', null, null, requestBody)
    .then((response) => {//1st API response (as mentioned above)
      const combinedResponse = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i = i + 1) {
        const obj = response[i];
        obj.Qty1 = response[i].Qty;
        obj.Qty2 = 0;
        combinedResponse.push(obj);
      }
      ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API2', null, null, requestBody)
        .then((innerResponse) => {//2nd API response (as mentioned above)
          for (let i = 0; i < innerResponse.length; i = i + 1) {
            const outerIndex = _.findIndex(combinedResponse, (o) => { return o.Location === innerResponse[i].Location && o.OrderNo === innerResponse[i].OrderNo; });
            let obj = {};
            if(outerIndex === -1) {
              obj = innerResponse[i];
              obj.Qty1 = 0;
              obj.Qty2 = innerResponse[i].Qty;
              combinedResponse.push(obj);
            } else {
              combinedResponse[outerIndex].Qty2 = innerResponse[i].Qty;
            }
          }
          this.setState({ combinedResponse: combinedResponse });
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('There was an error with ', err);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('There was an error with ', err);
    });
```

My code is not displaying the last/3rd object (getting only 1st two objects)

```
[
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty1": "46.1650",
"Qty2": "22.27",
"OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty1": "0",
"Qty2": "21.94",
"OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
"Status": null
  }
]
```

It will be very helpful if someone can rectify my code so that I get the proper combinedResponse. I am not interested in a Lodash/JQuery solution. I want a Plain Vanilla JS solution. Please provide a generic solution. Can someone help me in this regard. In my code the last object is not showing in the final array of object. My method is also quite complex. If someone can provide a more simpler response along with a fiddle/JSFiddle it will be of great help to me.

If someone answers my query please ignore the API calls, just use the two API responses.

Need a solution in Plain ES5 or ES6, not in JQuery/Underscore/Lodash.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use dependencies such as lodash when the JS native functions are just as succinct.

1) I suggest using `map` [(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to initialize your combined response from your first response while renaming the `Qty` field to `Qty1`.

2) Then iterate through the second response using `forEach` [(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and

3) find the corresponding order from your first response using `find` [(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

4) If you found a corresponding order from response 1, update it's `Qty2` field. Otherwise, insert a new order in your `combinedResponses`.

```js
let response1 = [
  {
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty": "46.1650",
    "OrderDate": null,
    "Status": null
  }
];

let response2 = [
  {
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty": "22.27",
    "OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
    "Status": null
  },
  {
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "526209",
    "Qty": "21.94",
    "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
    "Status": null
  },
  {
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "526209",
    "Qty": "65.36",
    "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
    "Status": null
  }
];

let combinedResponses = response1.map(({Location, OrderNo, Qty, OrderDate, Status}) =>
    ({Location, OrderNo, Qty1: Qty, Qty2: 0, OrderDate, Status,}));

response2.forEach(({Location, OrderNo, Qty, OrderDate, Status}) => {
  let find = combinedResponses.find(({Location: locationC, OrderNo: orderNoC})=> locationC === Location && orderNoC === OrderNo);
  if (find)
    find.Qty2 = Qty;
  else
    combinedResponses.push({Location, OrderNo, Qty1: 0, Qty2: Qty, OrderDate, Status,});
});

console.log(combinedResponses);
```

PS, also worth mentioning, you should look into flattening your promise/then nesting to make it more readable.

Comment: "[{\&quot;Location\&quot;:\&quot;Boston\&quot;,\&quot;OrderNo\&quot;:\&quot;406643\&quot;,\&quot;Qty1\&quot;:\&quot;46.1650\&quot;,\&quot;Qty2\&quot;:\&quot;22.27\&quot;,\&quot;OrderDate\&quot;:null,\&quot;Status\&quot;:null},{\&quot;Location\&quot;:\&quot;Boston\&quot;,\&quot;OrderNo\&quot;:\&quot;526209\&quot;,\&quot;Qty1\&quot;:0,\&quot;Qty2\&quot;:\&quot;65.36\&quot;,\&quot;OrderDate\&quot;:\&quot;01/03/0019\&quot;,\&quot;Status\&quot;:null}]"

Comment: Can you kindly remove this gibberish &quot in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k5aszqnm/3/ or https://jsfiddle.net/k5aszqnm/4/

Comment: Your output is again wrong. I am not getting the third object. {
"Location": "Boston",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty1": "0",
"Qty2": "21.94",
"OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
"Status": null
  },

Comment: @Scooby, from your question: "Please notice the comparing parameters are OrderNo and Location." Since we have 2 Bostn/526209 orders in the 2nd response, it's expected they'll overwrite each other per your statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that two of your items with matching `Location` and `orderNo` are both in the same `innerResponse` array so when you loop over the array and find the first element with `Location: 'Boston'` and `orderNo: 526209` you set `obj.Qty = 0` and `obj.Qty2 = innerResponse[i].Qty;` then when you loop again you find a matching element  and in your `else` block you overwrite `Qty2` with the value from the matching `obj`, so you either need to set `Qt1 = innerResponse[i].Qty`

The solution is instead of setting `obj.Qty1 = 0;` and `obj.Qty2 = innerResponse[i].Qty;` if there is no matching `obj` instead set `obj.Qty1 = innerResponse[i].Qty;` if there is no matching `obj` and then on the next loop it will add a `Qty2` and you'll get both values.

A better solution would be to make `Qty` an array on your created objects then you can add as many Qty values as you want.

For the index, you don't need lodash for this anymore, there is now a native findIndex in ES6, so you can get the index with:

```
const outerIndex = combinedResponse.findIndex(o => o.Location === innerResponse[i].Location && o.OrderNo === innerResponse[i].OrderNo);
```

You since you're using ES6 you can replace your for loops with Array.forEach for cleaner code.

The solution using `Qty1` and `Qt2` like in your original function looks like this:

```js
const ProjectAPI = {
  post(url, a, b, c) {
    if (url === '/ALLAPI/API1') {
      return Promise.resolve([{
        "Location": "Boston",
        "OrderNo": "406643",
        "Qty": "46.1650",
        "OrderDate": null,
        "Status": null
      }]);
    } else if (url === '/ALLAPI/API2') {
      return Promise.resolve([{
          "Location": "Boston",
          "OrderNo": "406643",
          "Qty": "22.27",
          "OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
          "Status": null
        },
        {
          "Location": "Boston",
          "OrderNo": "526209",
          "Qty": "21.94",
          "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
          "Status": null
        },
        {
          "Location": "Boston",
          "OrderNo": "526209",
          "Qty": "65.36",
          "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
          "Status": null
        }
      ]);
    }
  }
};

ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API1', null, null, {})
  .then((response) => { //1st API response (as mentioned above)
    const combinedResponse = [];
    response.forEach(r => {
      const obj = r;
      obj.Qty1 = r.Qty;
      obj.Qty2 = 0;
      combinedResponse.push(obj);
    });
    ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API2', null, null, {})
      .then((innerResponse) => { //2nd API response (as mentioned above)
        innerResponse.forEach(r => {
          const outerIndex = combinedResponse.findIndex(o => o.Location === r.Location && o.OrderNo === r.OrderNo);
          let obj = {};
          if (outerIndex === -1) {
            obj = r;
            obj.Qty1 = r.Qty;
            combinedResponse.push(obj);
          } else {
            combinedResponse[outerIndex].Qty2 = r.Qty;
          }
        });
        console.log("TCL: combinedResponse", combinedResponse)
        //   this.setState({ combinedResponse }); // We don't have react here so commenting this out
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('There was an error with ', err);
      });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('There was an error with ', err);
  });
```

And here's a solution using an array instead of a named key:

```js
const ProjectAPI = {
  post(url, a, b, c) {
    if (url === '/ALLAPI/API1') {
      return Promise.resolve([{
        "Location": "Boston",
        "OrderNo": "406643",
        "Qty": "46.1650",
        "OrderDate": null,
        "Status": null
      }]);
    } else if (url === '/ALLAPI/API2') {
      return Promise.resolve([{
          "Location": "Boston",
          "OrderNo": "406643",
          "Qty": "22.27",
          "OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
          "Status": null
        },
        {
          "Location": "Boston",
          "OrderNo": "526209",
          "Qty": "21.94",
          "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
          "Status": null
        },
        {
          "Location": "Boston",
          "OrderNo": "526209",
          "Qty": "65.36",
          "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
          "Status": null
        }
      ]);
    }
  }
};

ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API1', null, null, {})
  .then((response) => { //1st API response (as mentioned above)
    const combinedResponse = [];
    response.forEach(r => {
      const obj = Object.assign({}, r);
      obj.Qties = [r.Qty];
      combinedResponse.push(obj);
    });
    ProjectAPI.post('/ALLAPI/API2', null, null, {})
      .then((innerResponse) => { //2nd API response (as mentioned above)
        innerResponse.forEach(r => {
          const outerIndex = combinedResponse.findIndex(o => o.Location === r.Location && o.OrderNo === r.OrderNo);
          let obj = {};
          if (outerIndex === -1) {
            const obj = Object.assign({}, r);
            obj.Qties = [r.Qty];
            combinedResponse.push(obj);
          } else {
            combinedResponse[outerIndex].Qties.push(r.Qty);
          }
        });
        console.log("TCL: combinedResponse", combinedResponse)
        //   this.setState({ combinedResponse }); // We don't have react here so commenting this out
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('There was an error with ', err);
      });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('There was an error with ', err);
  });
```

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not mutate the original API responses.

```js
let response1 = [{
  Location: 'Boston',
  OrderNo: '406643',
  Qty: '46.1650',
  OrderDate: null,
  Status: null,
}, ];

let response2 = [{
    Location: 'Boston',
    OrderNo: '406643',
    Qty: '22.27',
    OrderDate: '28/11/0018',
    Status: null,
  },
  {
    Location: 'Boston',
    OrderNo: '526209',
    Qty: '21.94',
    OrderDate: '01/03/0019',
    Status: null,
  },
  {
    Location: 'Boston',
    OrderNo: '526209',
    Qty: '65.36',
    OrderDate: '01/03/0019',
    Status: null,
  },
];

const combinedResponse = response2.map(o => {
  const found = response1.find(v => v.Location === o.Location && v.OrderNo === o.OrderNo) || {};
  const clone = Object.assign({}, o);
  clone.Qty2 = clone.Qty || '0';
  clone.Qty1 = found.Qty || '0';
  delete clone.Qty;
  return clone;
});

console.log(combinedResponse);
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that `orderNo` uniquely identifies an entity, this one would be a simple, generic and easy to understand solution:

```js
let array1 = [{
  "Location": "Boston",
  "OrderNo": "406643",
  "Qty": "46.1650",
  "OrderDate": null,
  "Status": null
}]

let array2 = [{
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty": "22.27",
    "OrderDate": "28/11/0018",
    "Status": null
  },
  {
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "526209",
    "Qty": "21.94",
    "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
    "Status": null
  },
  {
    "Location": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "526209",
    "Qty": "65.36",
    "OrderDate": "01/03/0019",
    "Status": null
  }
]
let mergedArray = [];
let orderNumbers = array2.map(x => x.OrderNo);
array1.forEach((order, i) => {
  let mergedOrder = {
    "Location": order.Location,
    "OrderNo": order.OrderNo,
    "Qty1": order.Qty,
    "OrderDate": order.OrderDate,
    "Status": order.Status
  }
  let index = orderNumbers.indexOf(order.OrderNo);
  if (index <= 0) {
    mergedOrder.Qty2 = array2[index].Qty;
    //remove used element
    array2.splice(index, 1);
    orderNumbers.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    mergedOrder.Qty2 = "0";
  }
  mergedArray.push(mergedOrder);
})
//insert the remaining elements with 0 as qty1
array2.forEach(order => {
  let mergedOrder = {
    "Location": order.Location,
    "OrderNo": order.OrderNo,
    "Qty2": order.Qty,
    "OrderDate": order.OrderDate,
    "Status": order.Status
  }
  mergedOrder.Qty1 = "0";
  mergedArray.push(mergedOrder);

});

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Where `array1` and `array2` are your 2 responses.

Also note that using `indexOf` instead of `find` for example is advantageous for browser compatibility (especially IE).

Edit: Added jsfiddle. Please forgive me not using camelCase everywhere, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Can you kindly provide a demo in JSFiddle with consoled output. You can add this url for JSFiddle console - https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js

Comment: Just did that. Although my naming is not 100% following yours, you should get the idea and its easy enough to rewrite.

Comment: I only wanted Qty1 and Qty2. But your answer have all three Qty, Qty1 and Qty2

Comment: I updated the answer. That is just a matter of formatting, there is more ways to solve that. You could also map each array to a new one with updated Qty fields, or do it as I did in the example and create a new object for each merge.

Comment: "Given that orderNo uniquely identifies an entity" - is incorrect. There are two instances of `"OrderNo": "526209"`.